# adapt ID in a form (with AJAX ?) on rails 5

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a feedback modal box form that shows up when the user logs in, asking for a feedback on his/her last order. The form is then sent to the controller using AJAX.

Now I also want to use this feedback modalbox form on an 'orders history' page where there is a table of all orders of the user and next to each line a 'give a feedback' button. When clicking the button, I want the modal box to show up with the right order_id.

Here is the code:

_feedback_modal.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(@review, method: :post, url: review_path(current_user.id, Order.where(user_id: current_user.id, status: nil).last.id), remote: true) do |f| %>
      <%= f.input :rating, collection: [1,2,3,4,5], prompt: "Rate this meal", class: "col-sm-3" %>
      <%= f.label :comment %>
      <%= f.text_area :comment, class: "commentaire" %>
      <%= f.button :submit ,"Send", class: "btn" %>
    <% end %>
```

index.html.erb (page where the user lands when logged in)

```
[...]

<%= render 'feedback_modal' %>

[...]
```

reviews_controller.rb

```
  def create
    @review = Review.new(review_params)
    if @review.save
    respond_to do |f|
      f.js { render 'meals/feedback_validated' }
    end
  end
```

orders_history.html.erb

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Order Id</th>
      <th>Meal</th>
      <th>Restaurant</th>
      <th>pick-up time</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>status</th>
      <th>Feedback</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @orders.each do |o| %>
    <% if o.status == "canceled" %>
    <tr class="line_through" id="avis">
      <% else %>
      <tr id="avis">
        <% end %>
        <td><%= o.id %></td>
        <th><%= o.meal.name %></th>
        <th><%= o.meal.restaurant.name %></th>
        <td><%= o.pick_up_time%></td>
        <td><%= o.created_at.to_formatted_s(:long)%></td>
        <td><%= o.status%></td>
        <% if Review.where(order_id: o.id) == [] %>
        <td><a>Give a feedback</a></td>
        <% else %>
        <td>thank you for your feedback</td>
        <% end %>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

The problem is actually simple: I want the `Order.where(user_id: current_user.id, status: nil).last.id)`in the _feedback_modal.html.erb file to get changed depending on the order selected in the table.

Comment: So... what have you tried? What did you observe happening?

Comment: Aside: `if Review.where(order_id: o.id) == []` this is probably not optimal. you can't trust `where` to return an array (sometimes it returns an empty relation). you might prefer something like: `if Review.where(order_id: o.id).count == 0`, but even better Rails-standard would be to add `has_many :reviews` to the `Order` class and then do `if o.reviews.count == 0`